# WorkManager throws SecurityException on some Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-workmanager, securityexception

**Description**

The WorkManager lib schedules and alarm to track if it was force stopped. This happens in the `ForceStopRunnable`  class (see also: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/utils/ForceStopRunnable.java) which will run during initialization of the WorkManager. On some Samsung devices this will trigger a SecurityException, and as far as I know Samsung throws this exceptions when your apps schedules more than 500 alarms. The app isn't full of alarms, so i think `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will keep an old instance in memory of the cancelled version. But I haven't been able to reproduce this, and I don't see multiple copies of the alarm scheduled either.

Happens only on SDK 28 and some rare cases on SDK 29

**Question**

Does anyone else here have the same experience working with the WorkManager Library and knows a way how to reproduce this issue?

Is there a work-around for this issue?

**Crashlog**

`java.lang.SecurityException:  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:1966) at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1934) at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1884) at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set (IAlarmManager.java:240) at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl (AlarmManager.java:722) at android.app.AlarmManager.setExact (AlarmManager.java:571) at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.setAlarm (ForceStopRunnable.java:292) at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped (ForceStopRunnable.java:151) at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable (ForceStopRunnable.java:169) at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:101) at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run (SerialExecutor.java:91) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764) Caused by: android.os.RemoteException:  at com.android.server.SamsungAlarmManagerService.checkMaliciousAppLocked (SamsungAlarmManagerService.java:333) at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService.setImpl (AlarmManagerService.java:1758) at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$2.set (AlarmManagerService.java:2100) at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub.onTransact (IAlarmManager.java:92) at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:739)`

**Source:**
https://github.com/minvws/nl-covid19-notification-app-android

Comment: try scheduling > 500 jobs and you should be able to reproduce it. Looking at the source code, the file ExposureNotificationJob.kt schedules job without an ID and UPDATE/CANCEL flags. Do you really intend that? Could that be the one scheduling too many jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating WorkManager to version 2.6.0+ solved this issue. See following release notes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.6.0-alpha01

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if the application is creating too many alarms. This is not an `WorkManager` issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't get any crashes from other alarms in the app. The only crashes I see are are coming from the ForceStopRunnable: see androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.setAlarm (ForceStopRunnable.java:292)
The ForceStopRunnable is is part of the WorkManager. How would you explain that?

Comment: The alarm itself here is kind of irrelevant. This crash only occurs when you have > 500 alarms scheduled. It could be that `WorkManager` scheduled the 500th alarm. But that still means that the app scheduled the rest (which is the problem here).

Comment: @Rahul this not answer the question, in our case, even though we use ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, the issue still persists on Samsung. what's your recommendation on this? shall we use ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP?

Comment: Hi @Rahul, this is not related to this question. 
I have another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74514057/how-to-fix-crash-illegalstateexception-the-file-system-on-the-device-is-in-a-ba

I want to know when ForceStoppableRunnable class is used. The description at the top of the class is not very clear. Please help me understand.